# Sparse linear regression 0-norm and 1-norm

Tags: regression, feature-selection, regularization

We have a response $Y \in \Bbb R^n$ and predictors $X = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m)^T \in \Bbb R^{n \times m}$

The problem we want to solve is

$$\text{argmin}_{k \in \Bbb R^{m}} (\Vert Y - Xk \Vert_2^2 + \lambda \Vert k \Vert_0) \rightarrow k_0$$

However, it is NP-hard, so instead, we solve 
$$\text{argmin}_{k \in \Bbb R^{m}} (\Vert Y - Xk \Vert_2^2 + \lambda \Vert k \Vert_1) \rightarrow k_1$$

**In this paper** ["Learning physical descriptors for materials science by compressed sensing"](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/aa57bf/meta), it is said that

> with highly correlated features, $\lambda \Vert k \Vert_1$ may not be a good approximation for $\lambda \Vert k \Vert_0$

**My questions:**

Both $\lambda \Vert k \Vert_0$ and $\lambda \Vert k \Vert_1$ put a constraint on the number of non-zero components of vector $k$. But when features are correlated what is the advantage of the $k$ that is found by $\lambda \Vert k \Vert_0$?

Moreover, is there an intuitive example that demonstrates the point that I quoted above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If features are correlated, you should use [elastic net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization) and not lasso.
2. Roughly, if two features are correlated, lasso would choose the feature $i$ over $j$ if it has the better reward on the loss function, this means a smaller absolute value $|\beta_i|$ of the regression coefficient together with a good decrease in the prediction error $||y-X\beta||_2$.
3. On the other hand, the $l_0$-norm based penalty would choose the feature $i$ over $j$ if it leads to a good decrease in the prediction error *only*, since the size of the coefficient doesn't matter, just if it's different from zero (remember, $||\beta||_0=\#\lbrace\beta_k\neq0\rbrace$).
4. Now, my intuition would be that $l_1$- and $l_0$-norm penalties are equally bad at prediction of correct regression coefficients if features are correlated. The proof of Theorem 2 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04402.pdf) should illustrate why this is indeed the case. This would be in contradiction to the statement and example of the paper you cited, though.